# Error in tesseract_engine_internal, Unable to find training data

Tags: r, tesseract

I have a problem with (I am using Windows 10) running library(tesseract) which shows Warning message:
Unable to find English training data.

I have downloaded "eng.traineddata" from https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata

While try to run

```r
eng <- tesseract("eng")
```

It displays an error:

```
Error in tesseract_engine_internal(datapath, language, configs, opt_names,  : 
  Unable to find training data for: eng. Please consult manual for: ?tesseract_download
```

Comment: Did you use `tesseract_download("eng")` to download the english training data? If I do that I don't encounter any error when using  `tesseract("eng")`.

Comment: @phiver Yes, I have use tesseract_download("eng") also, but still displays the same error.

Answer (score 1):

You've probably used legacy, incompatible traineddata file. You'd need either `tessdata_fast` or `tessdata_best` data.

https://github.com/tesseract-ocr

Answer (score 0):

With R4.1 I had to create the file "C:\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract-OCR" and add  to it the eng.traineddata file downloaded from https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata_best/blob/main/eng.traineddata.